# How to change hosting?

Tags: web-hosting, godaddy

I have a website, here both domain and hosting are presently on `crazydomains.com`.au
Now I want to change hosting to GoDaddy but domain control should remain unchanged. I already purchased hosting from GoDaddy. I want know how to configure the domain?

Comment: Once in a while, you may come to realize that your website needs a new web host due to various circumstances. Instead of opening a new site it’s highly recommended you transfer website to new server host. Hosting migration is a simple process without any loss of data and money.

Answer (score 1):

You'll just need to change your nameserver. you can set this in your GoDaddy account by going to Domains > Manage My Domains > "tick" the box next to the domain you want to modify. Then on the top row, hit the dropdown next to "Nameservers" and select "Set name server". You should be able to select "Standard" and be good to go.

A bit of warning... GoDaddy is considered on of the worst hosts out there. You may want to look at different options.

Comment: I'll second GoDaddy as being the worst!

Answer (score 1):

After you purchase an account, you've got to set it up, know which domain you plan on using. If you're moving your website between hosting accounts within our system, you might need to remove the domain from an existing account

Once you have the files, you need to move them from your local computer to your hosting account (i.e. servers, which are accessible over the Internet).

After you've gotten the content on your hosting account, you'll want to preview it to make sure it looks good. For that information, see Previewing Your Website

you can officially make the switch from your old host to us by changing your DNS, which controls which hosting account/server your domain name loads

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change your nameservers to be those that `godaddy.com` provided you. This will "point" your domain to their web hosting services. Your current registrar will  remain unchanged. Your registrar should provide you with detailed instructions on how to do this.

Comment: Thanks for reply John. Could you tell me where I can found the nameservers on my Godadday Hosting account?

Comment: @Rajib once hosting is setup in Godaddy, assuming it's basic web hosting and shared they will email you letting you know the hosting account is ready and in the email will be the two nameservers to use for that hosting account. Those are the nameservers you'll put crazydomains.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple steps to change the hosting panel.

You already have the different account one for domain and second one hosting.

Simple find the name servers in new hosting panel and modify the new hosting name servers in domain panel instead of old name servers.

Then, your domain and hosting panel both will be integrated. Now download the total hosted files from old hosting and upload into new hosting account.